# How to add Columns to the PostgreSQL SQL where clause dynamically

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-9.3

I have a subquery that will return `1=1` or `ISNULL(optoutflag,'0')=0`. Now I am trying to use this return value in the main query `where` clause. If I'm appending directly it is throwing error like `argument of WHERE must be type Boolean, not type text`. Below is the query I'm using.

```
select * 
from ev_customer_v 
where (
  select * 
  from (select case
                 when a.cnt = '2' then 'ISNULL(optoutflag,\'0\')=\'0\''
                 when a.cnt = '0' then '1=1'
                end as columns
      from (
          select count(*) as cnt  
          FROM information_schema.columns 
          WHERE table_name='ev_customer_v' 
          and column_name in ('optoutflag1','deletedataflag1')
       ) a
   ) b
)
```

Comment: You will need a function using dynamic-sql for that

Comment: Unrelated, but: single quotes should be escaped by doubling them, not with a backslash.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, is there any other way that exists apart from the function. I already achieved with the help of function.I'm trying to find a solution without using the function.

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are trying to achieve there. Why don't you know what columns your table has? Do you want to check the value of the column `optoutflag1` but you don't know if it exists? And if it exists you only want to use it if there is another column named  `deletedataflag1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use next query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ev_customer_v 
JOIN (
  SELECT count(*) as cnt  
  FROM information_schema.columns 
  WHERE 
    table_name='ev_customer_v' AND
    column_name IN ('optoutflag1','deletedataflag1')
) a ON (a.cnt = 0 OR COALESCE(optoutflag, 0) = 0);
```

The joined table will return 0 or 2. In case 0 returned the first join condition `a.cnt = 0` will be true and all rows from `ev_customer_v` will be selected.
In other case first join condition will be false and select will use second condition `COALESCE(optoutflag, 0) = 0`